# Bootstrap site, I can either have the menu item resposive OR look correct but not both

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a menu where the login "username/password/sign in" buttons appear on the desktop site but in the mobile responsive version I jut want a "sign in" option that directs you to a sign in page.

I've used bootstrap-responsive.css to make the login-in boxes disappear when not in desktop, that works a treat but the "sign in" menu item will only either be responsive or look correctly formatted but not both

Here is the code

```
    <span class="visible-phone visible-tablet" >
<li class="dropdown">
<li>
<a href="sign_in.html">Sign in</a>
</li>
</li>
</span>


<li class="dropdown visible-desktop">
<div class="form-group">

<form class="form-inline" role="form">

<label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">

<label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">

<button type="submit" class="btn-u btn-u-default">Sign in</button>
<label><h6>Forgot Password?</h6></label>

</form>
</div>
</li>
```

This Will hide the menu in desktop view but display it in mobile/tablet view but the formatting is out, the form part of the code works perfectly

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using? if using 3.3.x, then should update `visible-phone`, `visible-tablet`, and `visible-desktop` to those mentioned here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: form inside an <li> is not a good practice, wrap it in a div. Also .form-group class belongs inside a form not outside

Answer (score 0):

I changed the "visible-phone" and "visible-tablet" into two separate entries and that seems to have worked

```
<li class="dropdown visible-phone">
<a href="page_login.html">Sign in</a>
</li>

<li class="dropdown visible-tablet">
<a href="page_login.html">Sign in</a>
</li>
```